# MongoDB Find max salary of a department

Tags: mongodb, max, aggregate

```
{ id: '101', name: 'Ethan', department: 'IT', salary: 5000 },
{ id: '102', name: 'Sally', department: 'Sales', salary: 6000 },
{ id: '103', name: 'Harry', department: 'HR', salary: 4000 },
{ id: '104', name: 'Jane', department: 'HR', salary: 3500 },
{ id: '105', name: 'Adam', department: 'IT', salary: 6000 },
{ id: '106', name: 'Henry', department: 'IT', salary: 8000 },
{ id: '107', name: 'Dianne', department: 'Sales', salary: 8000 },
{ id: '108', name: 'Barbie', department: 'Sales', salary: 7000 }
```

is there a way to find the max salary of a department? say IT

```
db.emp.aggregate([
  { $group:
    { _id: "$department",
      maxSalary: { $max: "$salary" }
    }
  }
])
```

this returns all departments but is there a way to only get for say IT department within the same aggregate statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `$match` to your aggregate statement. It works like this:

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
  { $match: { $or: [ { score: { $gt: 70, $lt: 90 } }, { views: { $gte: 1000 } } ] } },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] );
```

In your case you'd `$match` on a particular `department`.

To be clear, this operation first selects documents to process using the `$match` pipeline operator, and then pipes the results to the `$group` pipeline operator.

Comment: thanks! i was looking at $match in mongodb documentation too, and tested it, yup, that's the correct method! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$match`.

```
db.emp.aggregate([
    { $match: { department: "IT" } },
    { $group: { _id: "$department", maxSalary: { $max: "$salary" } } }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.emp.aggregate([
  { $group:
    { _id: "$department",
      maxSalary: { $max: "$salary" }
    }
  },
{ $match :{_id: 'IT'} } ])
```